# random git guardian emails after linking to Heroku

Tags: git, email, security, github, heroku

Does anyone know if Heroku uses git guardian? It's a service that monitors your git hub account for security vulnerabilities. I've been getting random emails from them -or someone portraying as them- since I linked my github repository to Heroku and I'm not sure why. It's almost every time I push something to my github account I get an email saying sensitive info is in my github repository. I do have a password in my pg credentials from a server file on github which I know I shouldn't but it's just a random test with a bogus password so it's not anything I'm worried about ATM. I can't seem to find anything about them being associated but it definitely started happening right after I gave Heroku my git hub credentials.

Comment: [heroku-guardian](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-guardian)?

Comment: No it says gitguardian. I just checked to make sure I didn't download Heroku guardian though and it's not on my computer. The more I look into it the more positive I am that heroku themselves don't have anything to do with it and it's not normal. I emailed the git guardian people and the email that it was sent to is different then the email address I'm getting these emails from. Not sure what it is. I've been getting all kinds of messages and job requests from people pretending to be companies they're not since I've been applying to more high paying remote positions.

Comment: Seems like there's a lot of fake listings on indeed.com. I reported one to the police that was confirmed by the company that they were portraying to be as fake. They already had an investigation going. Ever since I've been getting weird emails like this in my inbox -not spam- intermittently saying I'm subscribed to services and website I'm not lol. The timing was just weird I thought it might have been something Heroku does automatically that I just couldn't find anything about online. Thanks though!

Comment: They emailed me. I guess get git guardian is their subdomain. Sounds like they just monitor git hub and send people emails when they have security problems. Their website makes it sound like you have to subscribe but I guess they just do it.